# Where can I place these react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I had some hooks that I was using in my render of the code below - and they were working until I added a few useEffects. I am unceretain where to put these hooks to make them work again though - now I get the error "rendered more hooks than last time" -

The hooks I am trying to use are FormatDate and BandIcon. FormatDate gets data from props.post and BandIcon gets data from props.band. Can you help me figure out where to put these hooks so they work again?

I tried using them in the first useEffect by calling the hook to set a new part of state to hold that value... but that didnt work either.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Card, CardTitle, Badge, Button, CardFooter } from 'reactstrap'
import BandIcon from '../../../../uitls/BandIcon'
import FormatDate from '../../../../uitls/FormatDate'
import { Modal, ModalBody } from 'reactstrap'
import ReactMapGL, { Marker } from 'react-map-gl';
import { useAuth0 } from "../../../../react-auth0-spa";


let shouldUpdate = 0
let shouldUpdateStatus = 0
let shouldUpdateFavorites = 0

export default function ShowsPosts(props) {
    const { user } = useAuth0();
    const { post, band, _id, addRockOn, addFavorites, favorites } = props
    const [ day, setDay ] = useState('')
    const [ client, setClient ] = useState()
    const [ approved, setApproved ] = useState('')
    const [customQuotes, setCustomQuotes] = useState([])
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [ perfromanceDate, setPerformanceDate ] = useState('')
    const [ venueAddress, setVenueAddress ] = useState([])
    const [ viewPort, setViewport ] = useState();
    const [ total, setTotal ] = useState(0);
    const [ baseCost, setBaseCost ] = useState(0);
    const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
    const [isUser, setIsUser ] = useState(null)
    const [ rocks, setRocks ] = useState([])
    const [ renderIcon, setRenderIcon ] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        //Required Gig Details
        post.details.map(detail => {
            if(detail.title === "Performance Date"){
                setPerformanceDate(detail.detail)
            }

            if(detail.title === "Venue Address"){
                setVenueAddress(detail.detail)
            }

            if(detail.title === 'Base Cost'){
                setBaseCost(detail.money)
            }
            return null
        })

        //Client
        setClient(post.client)

        let slicedDay = new Date(post.details.map(detail => {
            if (detail.title === "Performance Date"){
                return detail.detail
            }else{
                return null
            }
        })).toDateString().slice(0,3)

        //Create Day Icon
        switch (slicedDay){
            case 'Mon':
                setDay('monday.svg')
                break;
            case 'Tue':
                setDay('tuesday.svg')
                break;
            case 'Wed':
                setDay('wednesday.svg')
                break;
            case 'Thu':
                setDay('thursday.svg')
                break;
            case 'Fri':
                setDay('friday.svg')
                break;
            case 'Sat':
                setDay('saturday.svg')
                break;
            default:
                console.log('switch didnt work')
        }   

        //Gig Status
        setApproved(post.approved)

        //Add Custom Qutoes - I added the return in the first part
        post.details.filter(detail => {
            if(detail.title !== "Performance Date" || detail.title !== "Base Cost" || detail.title !== "Venue Address"){
                return setCustomQuotes(quotes => [...quotes, detail])
            }else {
                return null
            }
        })

        //Set Total
        setTotal(post.total)

        setRocks(post.rockOn)

    }, [post])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(shouldUpdate >= 1){
            setViewport({
                latitude: post.details.filter(detail => {
                    if(detail.title === "Venue Address"){
                        return detail.detail[2][1]
                    }else {
                        return null
                    }
                })[0].detail[2][0] ,
                longitude: post.details.filter(detail => {
                    if(detail.title === "Venue Address"){
                        return detail.detail[2][1]
                    }else {
                        return null
                    }
                })[0].detail[2][1],
                width: '100%',
                height: 100,
                zoom: 12,
            })
        }else {
            shouldUpdate += 1
        }
    }, [venueAddress, post.details])

    const saveBookingStatus = async (newStatus) => {
        const token = await getTokenSilently();

        try {
            await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/posts/${_id}/${post.postId}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    Authorization: `bearer ${token}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "approved": newStatus
                    }
                )
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length) === band.userId){
            setIsUser(true)
        }else{
            setIsUser(false)
        }

    }, [band, user])

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);


    if( !post || !band || !user || !rocks || !approved ){
        console.log(post)
        console.log(band)
        console.log(user)
        console.log(rocks)
        console.log(approved)
        return <div>...loading</div>
    }

    const handleRockOn = () => {
        if(rocks.includes(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length))){
            setRocks(rocks => [...rocks.filter(rock => { return rock !== user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)})])
            addRockOn(post.postId, rocks.filter(rock => { return rock !== user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)}), props._id)
        }else {
            setRocks(rocks => [...rocks, user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)])
            addRockOn(post.postId, rocks.concat(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)), props._id)
        }
    }

    const handleFavorites = () => {
        addFavorites(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length), band)
    }

    return (
        <Card  color="light" className="my-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
            <span className="d-flex flex-row align-self-start mx-2 mt-2 mb-1">
                <img onClick={()=> {window.location.href=`/band/${_id}`}} src={BandIcon(band.bandGenre)} alt="Band Icon" style={{
                    width: "30px",
                    height: "30px",
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }}/>
                <span className="h6 mt-2 mx-1">
                    <strong onClick={()=> {window.location.href=`/band/${_id}`}} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>{band.bandName}</strong> - {FormatDate(post.date)}
                </span>
            </span>

            <Button 
            color="light" 
            id="dateCardPost"
            onClick={toggle} 
            className="d-flex flex-row align-self-start p-4 mx-5 mt-1 mb-3 w-75" 
            style={{cursor: "pointer",
                    pointerEvents: isUser ? "auto" : "none" }}
            >

                <img src={`/calendarIcons/${day}`} 
                className="mr-2" 
                alt=""
                style={{
                    width: "85px",
                    height: "85px",
                }}/>
                <Badge color="primary" className="align-self-start mx-1 mt-1" style={{
                    display: approved === 'pending' ? "block" : "none"
                }}>?</Badge>
                <Badge color="danger" className="align-self-start mx-1 mt-1" style={{
                    display: approved === 'false' ? "block" : "none"
                }}>X</Badge>
                <Badge color="success" className="align-self-start mx-1 mt-1" style={{
                    display: approved === 'true' ? "block" : "none"
                }}>✓</Badge>       
                <CardTitle className="d-flex flex-column mx-1 align-items-start">

                    <span><strong>{band.bandName}'s</strong> Show</span>

                    <span>on <strong>{perfromanceDate.slice(4)}</strong></span>

                    <span>at <strong>{venueAddress[1]} </strong></span>
                    <span>
                    is {approved === 'pending' ? 'un-confirmed!' : null}
                    {approved === 'false' ? 'cancelled!' : null}
                    {approved === 'true' ? 'confirmed!' : null}
                    </span>

                </CardTitle>

            </Button>
            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
                <ReactMapGL 
                        style={{zIndex: "2"}}
                        {...viewPort} 
                        mapboxApiAccessToken={"pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja2lzeW91cmZhbiIsImEiOiJjazh5azhjNjUxNzIwM21zZmdoZTBoM243In0.4ijWndTzChYeKo67PYSuAw"}
                        onViewportChange={viewport => setViewport(viewport)}
                        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/nickisyourfan/ck8ylgfk90kcb1iqoemkes76u"
                        >

                            <Marker 
                            latitude={post.details.filter(detail => {
                                if(detail.title === "Venue Address"){
                                    return detail.detail[2][1]
                                }else {
                                    return null
                                }
                            })[0].detail[2][0]} 
                            longitude={post.details.filter(detail => {
                                if(detail.title === "Venue Address"){
                                    return detail.detail[2][1]
                                }else {
                                    return null
                                }
                            })[0].detail[2][1]} 
                            offsetLeft={-25}
                            offsetTop={-20}>
                                <img src={BandIcon(band.bandGenre)} alt="Band Icon" style={{
                                width: "30px",
                                height: "30px",
                                }}/>
                            </Marker>
                        </ReactMapGL>
                <ModalBody className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                    <Card color="light" className="d-flex flex-column py-3 w-75 align-self-center justify-content-center align-items-center h5">{band.bandName}</Card>
                    <Card color="light" className="d-flex flex-column py-2 w-75 align-self-center justify-content-center align-items-center h6">
                        <span className="h6">{perfromanceDate}</span>
                        <span><strong>Venue: </strong>{venueAddress[1]}</span>
                        <span><strong>Address: </strong>{venueAddress[0]}</span>
                    </Card>
                    <Card color="light" className="d-flex flex-column py-2 w-75 align-self-center justify-content-center align-items-center h6">
                        <span><strong>Client: </strong>{client}</span>

                        <span><strong>Base Cost: </strong>${baseCost}</span>
                        {customQuotes.map(quote => {
                            if(quote.title !== 'Venue Address' || quote.title !== 'Base Cost' || quote.title !== 'Performance Date'){
                                return null
                            }else {
                                return <span key={quote.chargeId}><strong>{quote.title}: </strong>{quote.detail} ${quote.money}</span>
                            }
                        })}

                    </Card>
                    <Card color="light" className="d-flex flex-column py-2 w-75 align-self-center justify-content-center align-items-center h6">
                        <span><strong>Total: </strong>${total}</span>
                    </Card>
                </ModalBody>
                <Button 
                id="cancelBookingButton"
                onMouseEnter={() => { 
                    if(approved === 'true'){
                        document.getElementById('cancelBookingButton').innerHTML = 'Cancel Booking?'}
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                    if(approved === 'true'){
                        document.getElementById('cancelBookingButton').innerHTML = 'Booking Approved'
                    }
                }}
                onClick={() => {
                    setApproved('false') 
                    saveBookingStatus('false')
                }} 
                className="w-100 rounded-0" 
                color={approved === 'pending' ? 'danger' : 'success'} 
                style={{
                display: approved === 'pending' || approved === 'true' ? 'block' : 'none',
                }}>
                    {approved === 'pending' ? 'Decline Booking' : 'Booking Approved'}
                </Button>
                <Button 
                id="approveBookingButton"
                onMouseEnter={() => {
                    if(approved === 'false'){
                        document.getElementById('approveBookingButton').innerHTML = 'Re-Confirm Booking?'
                    }
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                    if(approved === 'false'){
                        document.getElementById('approveBookingButton').innerHTML = 'Booking Cancelled'
                    }
                }}
                onClick={() => {
                    setApproved('approved')
                    saveBookingStatus('approved')
                }} 
                className="w-100 rounded-0" 
                color={approved === 'false' ? 'danger' : 'success'} 
                style={{
                    display: approved === 'false' || approved === 'pending' ? 'block' : 'none',
                }}>
                    {approved === 'pending' ? 'Approve Booking' : 'Booking Cancelled'}
                </Button>
            </Modal>
            <CardFooter className="d-flex flex-row justfiy-content-between p-0">
                <Button onClick={handleRockOn} color={rocks.includes(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)) ? 'light active' : 'light'} className="d-flex w-50 h-100 rounded-0 justify-content-center shadow-none" >
                    <img src='/Rock-On.svg' style={{width: '27px', height: '27px'}} className="mr-2"/>
                    <span className="ml-2">{rocks.length}</span>
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={handleFavorites} color={favorites.includes(user.sub.slice(6, user.sub.length)) ? 'light active' : 'light'} className='w-50 h-100 rounded-0' style={{boxShadow: 'none'}}>
                    <img src='/FavoriteBand.svg' style={{width: '25px', height: '25px'}} />
                </Button>
            </CardFooter>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have lots of logic inside one component. I'll suggest beginning with splitting pieces of related logic into custom hooks in separate so you have less code inside your components and can you can find where are the errors while you are extracting them.

Implementation example:

```
function useViewport(venueAddress, postDetails) {
    const [viewPort, setViewport] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {

      if (shouldUpdate >= 1) {
        setViewport({
          latitude: post.details.filter((detail) => {
            if (detail.title === 'Venue Address') {
              return detail.detail[2][1];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })[0].detail[2][0],
          longitude: post.details.filter((detail) => {
            if (detail.title === 'Venue Address') {
              return detail.detail[2][1];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })[0].detail[2][1],
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
          zoom: 12,
        });
      } else {
        shouldUpdate += 1;
      }
    }, [venueAddress, postDetails]);

    return viewPort;
  }
```

Inside your `ShowsPosts` component:

```
useViewport(venueAddress, post.details);
```

Comment: Awesome! Yes I'll get started on this - I have been meaning to break this one down for a bit now.... On the other hand I have an if statement that was messing with the hooks called in the render - maybe you have a suggestion? I need the if statement to wait for the props post and band to come in... but the if statement breaks the rules of hooks.

Comment: You can use `if` statements but not when you initialize your hooks i.e if (isAvailable) { const [name, setName] = useState(''); }